# iOS MDM. DeviceInformation command

Tags: ios, mdm

1. I receive "CommandFormatError" on DeviceInformation commands.

That's what I'm sending as a DeviceInformation command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>">
<plist version="1.0">
     <dict><key>Command</key>
          <dict>
               <key>RequestType</key>
               <string>DeviceInformation</string>
          </dict>
          <key>CommandUUID</key>
          <string></string>
     </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4):

The MDM API documentation is a little ambiguous on this function. You actually need to query each of the values you wish to receive from the device. This is an example of a query for all values an iOS device may have. Devices that do not have a specific capability (for example an iPod Touch will not have a 3g connection, so no carrier related information) will return as null values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist
PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key>Command</key>
  <dict>
   <key>RequestType</key>
   <string>DeviceInformation</string>
   <key>Queries</key>
   <array>
    <string>AvailableDeviceCapacity</string>
    <string>BluetoothMAC</string>
    <string>BuildVersion</string>
    <string>CarrierSettingsVersion</string>
    <string>CurrentCarrierNetwork</string>
    <string>CurrentMCC</string>
    <string>CurrentMNC</string>
    <string>DataRoamingEnabled</string>
    <string>DeviceCapacity</string>
    <string>DeviceName</string>
    <string>ICCID</string>
    <string>IMEI</string>
    <string>IsRoaming</string>
    <string>Model</string>
    <string>ModelName</string>
    <string>ModemFirmwareVersion</string>
    <string>OSVersion</string>
    <string>PhoneNumber</string>
    <string>Product</string>
    <string>ProductName</string>
    <string>SIMCarrierNetwork</string>
    <string>SIMMCC</string>
    <string>SIMMNC</string>
    <string>SerialNumber</string>
    <string>UDID</string>
    <string>WiFiMAC</string>
    <string>UDID</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
  <key>CommandUUID</key>
  <string>94d45445-bf54-42df-9777-6280783b49e7</string>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You actually do not require a value in the CommandUUID key, however, the key itself MUST be present otherwise mdmd will not process the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your post shows that the `CommandUUID` value is empty; it cannot be empty as it is a required value.

Comment: The CommandUUID is generated on the server side before the command is prepared/sent to the iOS device. You use this identifier so that when the device checks back in later with the response to your command you will know which command it is responding to.